# JBoss Switchyard Metrics - where to find the data in the server?

Tags: jboss, metrics, switchyard

I'm using JBoss AS7 and can see metrics in the following link in the Admin console in my build environment.
http://localhost:10090/console/App.html#sy-metrics

But we don't have the console running in Production nor JMX.
Does JBoss store the metrics somewhere in the server installation which can be extracted for use? It will be useful to find out the services and the methods which are the biggest bottlenecks so that we can improve them.

Answer (score 0):

There's no store of server metrics - you can use something like JBoss Operations Network (https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/operations-network) to collect them, or if you enable JMX you could probably collect them in Prometheus.

I'm not sure whether you are using Fuse 6 or whether you are using community SwitchYard on top of AS 7 - if you're using Fuse 6, you can probably access the JMX beans through hawtio's jolokia instance.